# Crystal Reports XI Cross tab summarised field how to stop cell rows of the same value merging?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have created a cross tab however if I have a firstname field it merges the rows together if there are two names which are the same. How do you get it to display the names in the each row. In the example below Sarah is not displayed twice as the cells are merged together.

Firstname  Lastname
Judy   Collins
Sarah   Dane
   Smith
Joe   Dine
Mary   Lane

Comment: Can you edit your example table for clarity?  When you put it all on 1 line, it's rather difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you grouped your crosstab on the first name only.  I would recommend:

1. Make a new Formula (Call it "FullName")
2. In the formula, combine the first name and last name, e.g. something like {First Name}&{Last Name}
3. Edit your crosstab to group by the FullName formula instead.

Does this help?

#### EDIT

Based on your comment, I don't think your comment is with Crystal.  You need a "unique ID" of some sort, a distinct number for each person.  My original suggestion was trying to use the user's full name as a unique ID, but that won't work if your dataset is big enough to include multiple people with the same name. Does your dataset have any kind of unique ID?  What is this crosstab trying to display? There might be a better way.

Comment: The problem with that is when you export it to Excel the first and lastname will be in one column. Also we have a few occurrences where users have the same first and last name so they cells would still be merged together. Is there a way to prevent it from grouping the names at all?